# How to get last inserted item key in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working with Google App Engine and Python.
I have a model with Items.
Immediately after I insert an item with item.put()
I want to get it's key and redirect to a page using this key.

Something like:

```
redirectUrl = "/view/key/%s/" % item.key
self.redirect(redirectUrl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the initiative Scott Kirkwood. 
I was actually missing the ()

```
redirectUrl = "/view/key/%s/" % item.key()
self.redirect(redirectUrl)
```

Good to know that in google datastore you don't need to use anything like Scope_identity, but you can just get the item.key() just after item.put()..

Answer (score 4):

Also, item.put() returns the key as the result, so it's hardly ever necessary to fetch that key immediately again -- just change your sequence, e.g

```
  item.put()
  redirectUrl = "/view/key/%s/" % item.key()
```

into

```
  k = item.put()
  redirectUrl = "/view/key/%s/" % k
```

Answer (score 1):

After you did you `put()` you can run

```
item.key().id()
```

Getting the `id()` is slightly safer than just using `key()` directly, since you'd be indirectly calling `__str__()`, which may not happen in a non strincg context.

The other options is to call `id_or_name()`, but then you probably would already know what the name is in that case.